# Settingup Proxy with htmlunit

Tags: proxy, htmlunit

I am new on htmlunit, and with almost No knowledge of programming. 
In Centos - Webserver (for www.mydomain.com), i am trying to create a proxy.

I want my server to be used as proxy on request comming for www.mydomain.com and
send response as htmlsnapshot.

i saw some of the things like

> SocketAddress addr = new InetSocketAddress("xxx.xxx.xx.xxx", 8888);
>   Proxy proxy = new Proxy(Proxy.Type.HTTP, addr); //or Proxy.Type.SOCKS
>   URL url = new URL("http://mydomain.com/test"); URConnection conn =
>   url.openConnection(proxy);

But i wonder where to setup that. 
Can this be done entirely from apache..
i dont see any configuration file as such fo htmlunit.

BTW, i have installed htmlunit ( using jpackage repo)

Comment: Your question doesn't make much sense. HtmlUnit is a web browser. It can't be used to install a proxy server.

Comment: Ok, if i am wrong? I understood.

Html unit is just a headless browser, which opens the website virtually, gets the content as if the page was loaded and returns the url.

Comment: It's a headless browser, which connects to a web site exactly as FireFox would do, and downloads the page from the URL you gave it exactly as Firefox would do it. It doesn't do anything "virtually" or "as if the page was loaded". It loads the page.

Comment: Thanks for feedback, so, can i also create HTML snapshot and respond to any request coming in to original website.

Comment: There is no request coming to HtmlUnit. It's a browser, not a proxy or web server. HtmlUnit sends request. It doesn't receive any.

Comment: Hey, JB Nizet, Great, so how does that exactly works if i have to get snapshot of website?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/10741/discussion-between-tike-and-jb-nizet)

Answer (score 0):

HTMLUnit is GUI-Less browser for Java programs  Where did you see the code that you have included.  From memory I cannot recall the API even having a Proxy Class.  You can certainly point the WebClient at a proxy by passing in a ProxyConfig; and that is only there to declutter the WebClient Class.

Are you looking for a Proxy server, or a way to simulate a browser?

Comment: i would like to create html snapshot of original website. in a sense, request comes to original website i will pass the html snapshot.. 

which ideally is for crawler, SEO purpose.

Comment: So you want a spider then?  Try something like [JSpider](http://j-spider.sourceforge.net/) if you want to stay on the Java path.

Comment: My target is to use HtmlUnit as Developers.google says :     
If a lot of your content is created in JavaScript, you may want to consider using a technology such as a headless browser to create an HTML snapshot. For example, use HtmlUnit.